# How to run many JMX scripts simultaneously?

Tags: jmeter, jmx

I am using below command to run one `jmx` script in non-gui

```
jmeter -n -t "test.jmx" -r -l "testLog.csv"
```

I have a requirement to run like 5 scripts simultaneously in the same way.

Could you please help me with the correct command?

Comment: I can not merge all 5 scripts in to ONE jmx.. since each jmx is quniue (like endpoints,script path e.c.t...)

Comment: I just want to run all 5 individual scripts in same time.. in nonGUI mode. 
please help me

Comment: Please do not add extra information as comments, edit the question instead.

Comment: It will be helpful if you write exactly the 4 other scripts you want to run. It makes it easier to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is something you cannot achieve with command-line mode, the options are in:

1. If you're on Windows you can use [`start` command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) like:

   ```
   start jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result1.jtl
   start jmeter -n -t test2.jmx -l result2.jtl
   etc.
   ```
2. Use [parallel stages in Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/) to run your JMeter tests (if you're using [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) for CI/CD purposes like)

   ```
   pipeline {
       agent any

       stages {
           stage('Run JMeter Tests') {
               steps {
                   parallel(Test1: {
                       script {
                           sh 'jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result1.jtl'
                       }
                   }, Test2: {

                       script {
                           sh 'jmeter -n -t test2.jmx -l result2.jtl'
                       }
                   }, Test3: {

                       script
                               {
                                   sh 'jmeter -n -t test3.jmx -l result3.jtl'
                               }
                   }
                           //etc
                   )
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run your tests using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper like:

   ```
   ---
   execution:
   - scenario:
       script: test1.jmx
   - scenario: 
       script: test2.jmx
   - scenario: 
       script: test3.jmx
   #etc
   ```

   More information: [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests)

There are also other options which might differ depending on your environtment and infrastructure like:

- using [Ant Parallel Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html)
- using [GNU parallel command](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Dmitri T answer, in Linux you can execute in linux in parallel commands using background processes `&`

```
jmeter -n -t "test.jmx" -r -l "testLog.csv" & jmeter -n -t "test1.jmx" -r -l "testLog1.csv" & jmeter -n -t "test2.jmx" -r -l "testLog2.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like:

```
parallel jmeter -n -t test{}.jmx -r -l testLog{}.csv ::: 1 2 3 4 5
```

By default it will run one job per cpu-core. This can be adjusted with `--jobs`.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

For security reasons you should install GNU Parallel with your package manager, but if GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel